# SQL Server : bulk insert from csv string stored in column

Tags: sql-server, csv, insert, bulk

I store csv strings in a datatable. I later need to create a temporary table from that csv, but `BULK INSERT` only offers a filename as datasource.

Is there any possibility to import from a string?

Thank you and regards

Gabriel

Comment: I assume you mean you want to parse out the delimited data into rows? The best way to deal with that is to not store delimited data. It violates the very concept of relational data.

Comment: A small sample would be helpful.  Is your csv muli-line?  Does it contain headers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is not desirable to store unnormalized CSV data in a SQL Server table.  It makes it very hard to query and work with the data.  That being said, sometimes we have to live with bad design decisions.  That having been said, you could try writing your CSV column to file.  From the query menu of SSMS choose `SQLCMD` mode, and then type the following:

```
:OUT c:\path\to\your\file.csv
SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT csv_column FROM dbo.yourTable
```

Now that you have a bona fide CSV file, you should be able to use `BULK INSERT`.  Note that I have assumed here that the CSV data which you want to import is contained within a single column `csv_column`, and that the data is well formed (e.g. each record has the same number of commas etc.).

Comment: Is there a way to do this where entire CSV string is given through a VARCHAR(MAX) parameter passed to SP? Then do the bulk insert all in memory without saving CSV to physical file? In multi user environment you can see that a static file name can be stepped over by multiple users in concurrent scenario. I want to avoid devising a unique file naming scheme and then file cleanup system.